# Can't resolve method use() eventhough express installed

Tags: node.js, express

I have installed express and other methods are working for example:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();

//setting environment variable

var port=process.env.PORT||3000;

app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    res.send('<html><head><body<h1>Hello World</h1></head></html>');

});
```

But it can't resolve use method().
While I try to use

```
app.use('/assets',express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

static and use can't be resolved. Assume my path of file  is correct . Get is working but use , static are not working.

Comment: Do you have the `use` before the `get`?

Comment: Yeah..use is before get because I need to use assets for middleware as css file to use in get ::app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    res.send('<html><head><link href=assets/style.css ' +
        'type=text/css rel="stylesheet"' +
        '/><body<h1>Hello World</h1></head></html>');

});

Comment: I think you need to include in your question a representation of your directory structure and file locations.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to do `app.use()` and `express.static()` in some other module where the `app` variable and the `express` variable are not available.  You can `require()` in `express` to get `express.static()` and you can share the `app` variable to this other module.